# Connection on fiber bundle of generic fiber

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, fiber-bundles, connections

I am looking for references about connections on a generic fiber bundle. 
A lot of books deal with connections on vector bundles, some books as the Kobayashi-Nomizu generalize the concept of connection to principal bundles. I know that exists also a more general notion of connection on fiber bundles (for example in Kolar-Michor-Slovak's book "Natural Operators in Differential Geometry" it is shown using horizontal and vertical bundles), but I have had some difficulties in finding other good references.

Can someone suggest me a good book?

This question is different from [Reference Request for Fibre Bundle Theory from the Smooth Manifold Point of View](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589593/reference-request-for-fibre-bundle-theory-from-the-smooth-manifold-point-of-view) as mine it is more specific on connections, among the books suggested there only the abovementioned K-M-S deals with  connections on general fiber bundles.

Comment: I am not sure what's wrong with the references that you already have. In addition, take a look here: http://www.math.wichita.edu/~pparker/research/Ryan_Justin_SP2014.pdf

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it, but you know, when learning something it is always better to have more then one source.

Comment: True, but in this case, very few sources cover Ehresmann connections.

Comment: ... in this degree of generality. I think, KMS is your best option.