# Covariant derivative vs. Ehresmann connection

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles, connections

I know about Ehresmann connections on fiber bundles and covariant derivatives as an (equivalent) way to define linear Ehresmann connections on vector bundles. My question is:

Is there any notion of covariant derivative equivalent to Ehresmann connection in the most general setting concerning fiber bundles?

When I say "the most general setting", I am emphasizing that the fiber bundle do not have any further structure than being just a fiber bundle (it may not be a vector bundle nor a principal bundle).

Thanks in advance,

Diego

PS: I'm concerning the case when the fiber bundles are smooth. I don't worry about the non smooth case.

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2543508/connection-on-fiber-bundle-of-generic-fiber?rq=1)?

Answer (score 2):

No although you can still define parallel transport on fiber bundles. Given the extra structure of a principal bundle, then you have the covariant derivative from a principal connection. See [Natural Operator in Differential Geometry](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjwr_jj__LdAhXGhKYKHVyjCSEQFjAAegQICRAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.emis.de%2Fmonographs%2FKSM%2Fkmsbookh.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1xw-ftog1BCPh9FPbyriAp) for more details.

As for the completness in this very book there is a theorem saying that all fiber bundles admits complete connections (i.e. Ereshmann connections), but the proof is wrong. There is a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.03847) in which the author claims to have found a proof, however I am not sure whether he got it right (he could, just I don't know).

Comment: Thanks a lot! @Baol

Answer (score 2):

I think there is an analog of a covariant derivative associated to an Ehresmann connection, but it produces a more complicated object. Consider a fiber bundle $p:E\to M$ with fiber $F$, and a smooth section $s:M\to E$. Then you can take the tangen map $Ts:TM\to TF$ and use the Ehresmann connection to projctet to the vertical subbundle $VF=\ker(Tp)\subset TF$. So for each $x\in M$, this produces a linear map $T_xM\to V_{s(x)}F$ that can be interpreted as a smooth section of $T^*M\otimes s^*VF$, which is a good analog of the standard covariant derivative. Alternatively, you can insert a vector field $\xi$ on $M$ to obtain a section $\nabla_\xi s$ of $s^*VF$.

This exactly reproduces the standard concept in the case that $F$ is a vector bundle, since in that case $VF$ can be naturally identified with $p^*F$ and thus $s^*VF$ is canonically identified with $F$ for any section $s$.